# How best to store multi-dimensional timeseries data in a (R)DBMS environment?

Tags: database-design, management, time-series-database

Any suggestions on how multi-dimensional time-series data should be stored and organized in an RDBMS environment? For example, we have multiple experiments from multiple customers. This translates well to say a NetCDF file type structure, where one NetCDF can be for one customer project, and it contains several data variables overtime. [This image](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/data-structures.html#dataset) explains the concept.

From my [preliminary research](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/developer/en/entry/netcdf_schema_language), this seems like an [unsolved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191897/how-to-store-multidimensional-data) or one with a [complicated solution](https://newtraell.cs.uchicago.edu/files/ms_paper/sthaler.pdf). Are there any recent (not necessarily optimal) attempts at this?

Comment: Don't mix logical and physical models for your data. Determine the correct logical model first, then use your DBMS features to translate it to a physical model that performs well enough.

Comment: @mustaccio: can you clarify your comment? I feel the multi-dimensional representation is the correct logical structure and now I want to figure out how I should organize it in an RDMS environment to support scale.

Comment: "Representation" is not the model; it's the representation of a model. Define a model first, then choose a good representation of it. So far you have not described your model.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.  Data from experiments in an Apple orchard will contain different information from a quality control experiment on toasters.  Unless you know how to compare apples and toasters, I don't see any logical reason to store the data in the same set of relational tables.

Comment: @Michael Kutz: We do not necessarily want to aggregate multiple customers and a different project for each customer. But for each project, we run multiple iterations, ie, multiple apples. It would be good if we could store the data for multiple apples together.

Comment: @mustaccio: Our experimental data is tabular (around 2GB per experiment, at 1-sec timestep). We measure data from multiple sensors for the Device Under Test (DUT).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating things.  For this example

[image]

Modeling this as a relational table is simple:

```
create table Forecast
( 
  reference_time datetime,
  latitude float,
  longitude float,
  precipitation float,
  temperature float,
  constraint primary key (reference_time,latitude,longitude)
)
```

It may not be extremely efficient for storage space and processing, depending on data structures and algorithms used by 
the RDBMS that implements it.  But it's logically very straightforward to model this as a relation.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft: I feel this is the solution in the SO post I linked. While simple to implement, I wonder what can be better than this, as this would result in one big table. Other concern is about organizing the data. So I could have one db per customer, with one table per project, that has primary_key(experiment_no, time), which has the side-effect of losing timeseries-based optimization in data-access.

Comment: Those are good questions, but likely to depend on the RDBMS, the environment, the number of customers, experiments, etc.

Comment: And even if we settle with this design, one feature of NetCDF I really miss in the RDBMS design is metadata, and the prospect of having data-variable specific metadata. Any suggestions on how to organize metadata for a project and an experiment.